# Who resolves properties in akka config files?

Tags: sbt, akka, config

I have project with SBT and akka. There is a akka config file:

```
akka {
  loglevel = ${?LOG_LEVEL}
}
```

I understand that `${?` refers to read property from System properties but who is responsitive for that? It is SBT or akka feature? Also how does it names? I do not understand what to search about how does this mechanism works - the "property resolving" search request for sbt and akka return so many resources without such pretty `{${?}' syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).